# chess problem , probability the former champion maintains his status

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am taking a probability course on Edx and I am trying to answer part c on this question. my answer seems not correct based on their answer and am not sure why. The course in on archive now, so no TA to ask.
A chess tournament problem. This year's Belmont chess champion is to be selected by the following procedure. Bo and Ci, the leading challengers, first play a two-game match. If one of them wins both games, he gets to play a two-game second round with Al, the current champion. Al retains his championship unless a second round is required and the challenger beats Al in both games. If Al wins the initial game of the second round, no more games are played.

Furthermore, we know the following:
 The probability that Bo will beat Ci in any particular game is 0.6.
 The probability that Al will beat Bo in any particular game is 0.5.
 The probability that Al will beat Ci in any particular game is 0.7.
 Assume no tie games are possible and all games are independent.
(c) Al will retain his championship this year.

My solution: P(No second round) + P( there is a second round and Ai wins first game ) + P( there is a second game and Bo wins the first game in second round but lost the second game in second round). P( there is a second round and Ai wins first game ) + P( there is a second game and Ci wins the first game in second round but lost the second game in second round).

in numbers =$ (1-0.52) + (0.52 \cdot (0.5)^2) + (0.52 \cdot 0.5) + (0.52 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.7) + (0.52  \cdot 0.7)$

what is the wrong with my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your answer is all the terms that go to the second round.  The first, $0.52 \cdot 0.5^2,$ is supposed to be the chance that Bo wins the first round and the first game with Al, then Al wins the second game of the second round.  Instead of $0.52$ it should be $0.36$, the chance Bo won the first round.  This carries over to the other three terms.

An easier approach is to note that Al retains the championship unless Bo or Ci wins four games in a row.  Bo wins four with probability $0.6^2\cdot 0.5^2=0.09$ and Ci wins four with probability $0.4^2 \cdot 0.3^2=0.0144$, so Al retains the championship with probability $1-0.09-0.0144=0.8956$

Comment: Thank you,make sense now,

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate P( there is a second game and Bo wins the first game in second round but lost the second game in second round), your calculation is multiplying the probability of there being a second round and the probability of Bo beating and then loosing to Al.

This is wrong, as the probability of there being a second round also includes the case where Ci wins the first round. You should multiply the probability of Bo winning the first round with the probability of Bo beating and then loosing to Al.

Comment: Thank you,make sense now,